# RangeError [COLOR_RANGE]: Color must be within the range 0 - 16777215 (0xFFFFFF)

Tags: discord.js

I made an announcement command for my discord.js bot, using a command handler. The issue is, that I am entering a valid decimal value when it asks for the embed color, but it's saying it's not! I tried without the Number() and with, but both produce the same error. Here is the code, which can be found below:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'post',
    description: 'Posts a message for the server,',
    arguments: [],
    guildOnly: true,
    userPermissions: [
        'MANAGE_GUILD'
    ],
    clientPermissions: [
        'SEND_MESSAGES'
    ],
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {
        if (args >= 1) {
            let thisEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('**Error**')
                .setDescription('**Incorrect arguments**')
                .setColor(15536401)
                .setFooter('Veriro')
            await message.channel.send(thisEmbed)
            return
        }

        let thisEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('**Title**')
            .setDescription('What should the title of the announcement be?')
            .setFooter('Announcement Prompt')
            .setColor(950765)
        
        let m = await message.channel.send(thisEmbed)
        var ret = false;
        let titleMessage = (await message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 300000, error: ['time'] }).catch( err => { ret = true })).first()

        if (!titleMessage || ret == true) {
            message.channel.send('Cancelled prompt due to time out.')
            return
        }

        let thisEmbed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('**Colour**')
        .setDescription('Please provide the decimal colour of the embed.')
        .setFooter('Announcement Prompt')
        .setColor(950765)
        let m2 = await message.channel.send(thisEmbed2)
        var ret2 = false;
        let colorMessage = (await message.channel.awaitMessages(m2 => m2.author.id == message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 300000, error: ['time'] }).catch( err => { ret2 = true })).first()

        if (!colorMessage || ret2 == true) {
            message.channel.send('Cancelled prompt due to time out.')
            return
        }

        let thisEmbed3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('**Description**')
            .setDescription('What should the description be for embed be?')
            .setFooter('Announcement Prompt')
            .setColor(950765)
        let m3 = await message.channel.send(thisEmbed3)
        let ret3 = false;
        let descriptionMessage = (await message.channel.awaitMessages(m3 => m3.author.id == message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 300000, error: ['time'] }).catch( err => { ret3 = true })).first()

        if (!descriptionMessage || ret3 == true) {
            message.channel.send('Cancelled prompt due to time out.')
            return
        }

        let thisEmbed4 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('**Channel**')
            .setDescription('Which channel to send to?')
            .setFooter('Announcement Prompt')
            .setColor(950765)
        let m4 = await message.channel.send(thisEmbed4)
        let ret4 = false;
        let channelMessage = (await message.channel.awaitMessages(m4 => m4.author.id == message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 300000, error: ['time'] }).catch( err => { ret4 = true })).first()

        if (!channelMessage || ret4 == true) {
            message.channel.send('Cancelled prompt due to time out.')
            return
        }

        
        let finalEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(titleMessage)
            .setDescription(descriptionMessage)
            .setColor(Number(colorMessage))
        
        let theChannel = client.channels.get(channelMessage)

        await theChannel.send(finalEmbed)
        
        


        

        
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

RangeError [COLOR_RANGE]: Color must be within the range 0 - 16777215 (0xFFFFFF)

Why does this happen? I'm entering a valid decimal color in!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for `.setColor()` should be a string starting with either `#` or `0x`

```
.setColor('0x950765')
```

Or

```
.setColor('#095765')
```